# Proper Use of Nested Routes

Tags: ember.js, routes

I was trying to get the following working:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('games', function() {
        this.route('game', {path: '/:game_id'}, function() {});
    });
});
```

I had a directory structure like so:

```
templates
  - games
    - index.hbs
    - game.hbs
```

Clearly, this wasn't working. I couldn't really figure out how to get game.hbs to render. After doing some research, I stumbled on an [article](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/ember-routing-the-when-and-why-of-nesting) from 2013 and that led me to this solution:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('games', function() {});
    this.route('game', {path: 'games/:game_id'}, function() {});
});

templates
  - games
    - index.hbs
  - game
    - index.hbs
```

Note that I had to include the empty `function() { }` in both routes to get the subdirectory structure to work.

I'm using Ember 1.13.7 and I'm wondering if this is still the correct approach. Or is there a way I can nest the game route without having anything additional on the path to get it to work?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to think about nested routes is this: Do you want your UI to be nested? If you do, then nest the routes. If you do not want your UI to be nested, then do not nest your routes.

I could go on but there is a really good (and recent) article regarding this that you may want to check out - http://fromrailstoember.com/9-nested-routes-equals-nested-ui/

Just wanted to leave this answer here so people know that there is a method behind nested routes. I see you got it working but you should still make sure it's done the way the framework intended you to do it.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm also asking. In my situation, what does the framework suggesting be done? I'll read that article. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Here's a [quick demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/magivijere/edit?html,js,output) outside of the article - It shows how a nested UI works inside it's parent template. Click the 'one', 'two', 'three' links to see the nested templates.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I understand how they work. My question was more about preferred by the framework / design. I suppose that isn't the best question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out...

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('games', function() {
        this.route('game', {path: '/:game_id'}, function() {});
    });
});
```

I can define the route like above and the link-to helper has to change from:

```
{{#link-to 'game' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
```

to

```
{{#link-to 'games.game' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
```